# Custom CouchDb SSL Certificate Verification

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I'm trying to configure CouchDB to use SSL on IoT devices accessed via IP. I'm trying to avoid adding a webserver as a reverse proxy in an attempt to keep things as lightweight as possible and instead use CouchDb's builtin SSL functionality.

The problem I'm running into is that replication is going to fail Common Name certificate verification because we're accessing via IP. I'm hoping to use a custom verification function to check certificate thumbprint instead. It looks like [verify_fun](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/http.html#ssl/verify_fun) combined with someting like this [ssl_verify_fingerprint function](https://github.com/deadtrickster/ssl_verify_fun.erl/blob/master/src/ssl_verify_fingerprint.erl) is probably what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to use it in the config file. How can I update this config line to use a custom function?

`verify_fun = {Module, VerifyFun}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question fully. By "nodes" do you mean a Node.js environment? You can configure CouchDb itself to use SSL, but normally you would serve your HTML from a web server and use CouchDb to provide information for the web pages. So users would not directly access CouchDb in that scenario.

The common solution is to configure Apache, Nginx or some other web server as a reverse proxy and SSL end point. You can then redirect incoming HTTPS requests to other services on your server such as Node.js. There are many guides on setting up a reverse proxy with SSL such as [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) and [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04). You can use "[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)" for secure certificates. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for the confusion. I edited the question to hopefully clarify. The nodes I'm referring to are IoT devices that are hosting CouchDb. I'm hoping to avoid adding a web server and use the built in SSL functionality to keep it as lightweight as possible. It doesn't look like too many people are using it though, so maybe I don't have much of a choice

Comment: Ok no worries! I don't think I can help then. I have configured CouchDb for SSL, though in the end I decided the reverse proxy provided a simpler and more useful solution. I have not tried to use the verification function you mention but hopefully someone else on Stack can help.